# MyISAM locks on large select statements

Tags: mysql, myisam

On a MyISAM engine MySQL server (5.1)

We have some large query to make a report (1 million results). I notice that these select statements lock the tables. 
I don't find a real explanation for this on the internet. From what I understand the tables should only lock when switching between select and insert (etc) statements.

I found someone with the same problem http://devoluk.com/mysql-myisam-table-lock-issue.html

When i convert the tables to innodb the table locks don't happen. Unfortunately converting in production takes days, so its not really an option.

Did someone have the same issue, or how to make it non blocking?

Comment: MyISAM always locks the table on a SELECT / UPDATE process. InnoDB only locks the attended rows rather than the whole table.

Comment: see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html

Answer (score 2):

Thread 1:  SELECT ... -- long running
Thread 2:  INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE/etc ... -- will wait for thread 1 to finish
Thread 3:  SELECT ... -- will wait for thread 2

A SELECT does a shared-read lock, which allows other SELECTs, but not any writes.

MyISAM *cannot* have "deadlocks".  (The referenced article is probably misusing that term.)

Also, check out [`INSERT DELAYED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html), but be aware of its caveats.

And [`LOW_PRIORITY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)